# LookField Update with PickList of another Object

Tags: trigger, picklist, error, list

I have two Objects **`DealSheet__c`**, **`Change_Log__c`**.

Now I want To Update One  Lookup field(**`Counter_Party__c`**) of **`DealSheet__c`** with the pickList Field(**`Cp_list__c`**) of **`Change_Log__c`**.

**Trigger Handler Code:**

```
public class ChangeelLogPic {
    public static void ChangeLog(List < Change_Log__c > newlist, List < Change_Log__c > oldlist) {
        list < Dealsheet__c > HistoryData = new List < Dealsheet__c > ();
        Set < ID > ChangelogIds = new set < ID > ();
        For(Change_Log__c change: newlist) {
            ChangelogIds.add(change.id);
            Dealsheet__c hobject = new Dealsheet__c();
            hobject.Counter_Party__c = change.CP_List__c;
            hobject.CP_Trader__c = change.CP_Trader1__c;
            historyData.add(hobject);
        }
        try {
            insert HistoryData;
        } catch (Exception e) {


        }
    }
}
```

---

but when i am running this i am getting error

> "Invalid Id CpListName"

How to sort it out Tell me..Thanks in Advance

Comment: is `CP_List__c` picklist string equal with the Counter_Party__c Record's Name ?

Comment: What is CP_List__c?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup field will only accept Id values, in your case I guess you are trying to put some predefined string into this field - and this is causing error.

Answer (score 0):

A lookup field needs to be set with the record Id of the related object, not it's display name. I see your code uses Counter_Party__c assigns to picklist value.
It should be Counter_Party__r.Id

Comment: If your CP_List__c has same name values as Counter_Party__c records, then you need to query all the records in Counter_Party__c  and put in map<String, Counter_Party__c>. Using this map , you can get the Counter_Party__c record for the given picklist value. Then you can use, 
**_hobject.Counter_Party__c = map.get(CP_List__c);**

Comment: Sry I am Unable to write